# How to add or change API in openmeeting?

Tags: java, openlaszlo, openmeetings

I am Using Ubuntu 12.04 o.s.i have install openmeetings in my system and now i try to add few API of openmeetings but i don't know in which file i should change it. so kindly help me.i use jdk 1.7 in my system. kindly help me where to change API setting in openmeetings.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should concentrate on using the Rest and SOAP API if you want to integrate Openmeetings somewhere.
Other then that I am sorry but the question itself is that general that it is almost impossible to answer.
Maybe you can get somebody on the mailing list to help you further:
http://openmeetings.apache.org/mail-lists.html